# Get json data in controller and use data as vars and functions etc

Tags: json, angularjs

I am pretty new to Angular JS and I am currently building an order form where a user can use a form to graphically build their item.
I have a json file, which lists all elements of the products (frame, background, letters, message) and their SKU's and prices.
I can get the json in to the app as 'products' but i'd like to be able to get this data as per the users selection, i.e if the user chooses the gold frame, i'd like to make a variable which includes the SKU, price and weight of the gold frame from the json.
Hope that makes sense.

There is a demo located at https://jsfiddle.net/3kd796wL/ and this is my json file:

```
{
  "products":
    {
      "frames": {
        "plastic": {
          "SKU": "PLA",
          "price": 1.00,
          "weight": 1.00
        },
        "wood": {
          "SKU": "WOO",
          "price": 6.00,
          "weight": 3.00
        },
        "silver": {
          "SKU": "SIL",
          "price": 12.00,
          "weight": 6.00
        },
        "gold": {
          "SKU": "GOL",
          "price": 18.00,
          "weight": 12.00
        }
      },
      "backgrounds":{
        "feet":{
          "SKU": "BK01",
          "price": 1.00,
          "weight": 0
        },
        "flowers":{
          "SKU": "BK02",
          "price": 1.00,
          "weight": 0
        },
        "rabbits":{
          "SKU": "BK01",
          "price": 1.00,
          "weight": 0
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would i be able to put this in the controller, or is it best to make a factory?

Answer (score 0):

change the code of selection of frame as below

```
 <label for="frame">Choose a frame</label>{{frame}}
    <select name="frame" id="frame" class="form-control" ng-model="frame" ng-options="key for (key, value) in products.products.frames">
    </select>
```

In above code snippet, I have used **ng-options** which creates options by iterating over the array of objects. set **ng-model='frame'** so whenever you change any thing it will be effected on that object.For reference check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions